# Django appending /None to url

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i am creating a logic for users to save posts as favourite, i finished creating but when i header over to the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/design/ui-ux/learn-ui-the-easy-way/save/` it automatically refreshes it self and now appends `None` to the url like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/design/ui-ux/learn-ui-the-easy-way/save/None` and that is not what i am expecting.

views.py

```
@login_required
def designtut_favourite(request, designcat_slug, design_slug):
    user = request.user
    designtut = DesignTutorial.objects.get(slug=design_slug)

    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)

    if profile.favourite_design.filter(slug=design_slug).exists():
        profile.favourite_design.remove(designtut)
    else:
        profile.favourite_design.add(designtut)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    favourite_design = models.ManyToManyField(DesignTutorial)
```

urls.py

```
path('design/<designcat_slug>/<design_slug>/save/', views.designtut_favourite, name="design-save"),
```

template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'base:design-save' designtut.designcat.slug designtut.slug %}"><i class="fas fa-heart" "></i><span>Save</span></a>
```

Comment: Hi. Can you share your urls.py and the form in your HTML?

Comment: @enesislam i have updated the question with my urls.py and template

Comment: Check the value of request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'). Does it have the value None? It is also better to have a fixed redirect than using the referer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**views.py**

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse
# import ALLOWED_HOSTS from your settings.py here!


@login_required
def designtut_favourite(request, designcat_slug, design_slug):
    user = request.user
    designtut = DesignTutorial.objects.get(slug=design_slug)

    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)

    if profile.favourite_design.filter(slug=design_slug).exists():
        profile.favourite_design.remove(designtut)
    else:
        profile.favourite_design.add(designtut)

    net_location = urlparse(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')).netloc
    for allowed_host in ALLOWED_HOSTS:
        if net_location in allowed_host:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

It is important to note, that blindly redirecting to a site given in the request poses a **security risk**. Therefor I tried including a check with the `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. This should redirect to the landing page, if there is a `None` value in it, but also if somebody is lured into a phishing site.